# If statements not being detected

Tags: java, netbeans, if-statement

I am using Netbeans 7.1.2 IDE.
My code is here:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String search1;
    search1 = jTextField1.getText();
    search1.toLowerCase();
    jTextField2.setText("tes1");
    // stone
    if (search1=="stone" || search1=="rock" || search1=="1")
    {
        jTextField2.setText("Stone: 1");
    }

    // grass
    else if (search1=="Grass" || search1=="grass")
    {
        jTextField2.setText("Grass: 2");
    }

    // dirt
    else if (search1=="Dirt" || search1=="dirt" || search1=="Soil" || search1=="soil")
    {
        jTextField2.setText("Dirt: 3");
    }

    // cobblestone
    else if (search1=="cobblestone" || search1=="cobble")
    {
        jTextField2.setText("Cobblestone: 4");
    }

    else;
    {   
        jTextField2.setText("Unknown Block");
    }
}
```

When I run the build, and I input 'stone' into jTextField1, and hit jButton1, it just gives me "Unknown Block", when an If statement specifies that it should set jTextField to "Stone: 1". Am I doing something wrong? Sorry if this ends up being a completely obvious error.

Comment: You have a stray semicolon `else;`.

Comment: Well at elast you got the problem Evan while everyone was biting the reference ==! Cheers!

Comment: Also, change `search1.toLowerCase();` to `search1 = search1.toLowerCase();`.

Answer (score 5):

Compare `String` using `equals()`

```
if (search1.equals("stone") || search1.equals("rock") || search1.equals("1"))
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) for more information.

`==` compares references,not the values. In your case, you want to check for the value equality, not the reference equality.

---

EDIT:

Remember, you need to do all your `String` comparisons that way.

Besides,

you have an unwanted `;` here:

```
  else;
    {   
        jTextField2.setText("Unknown Block");
    }
```

remove that `;` after `else`.

Comment: You might wanna make it into a switch statement (If you are using Java 1.7).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.equals` to check strings, like so:

`if (search1.equals("stone") || search1.equals("rock") || search1.equals("1"))`

Answer (score 1):

So first don't compare String using `==` but use `equals()` instead then in the last else statement you have add a `;` that means the end of the else (so `jTextField2.setText("Unknown Block")` is always executed). You should drop it.

```
else; //<==Remove the ;
{   
    jTextField2.setText("Unknown Block");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do what Kazekage Gaara is telling. But in this instance the problem is not that. in the following statement remove the `;` after else.

```
else;
{   
    jTextField2.setText("Unknown Block");
}
```

What happens here is

```
{   
    jTextField2.setText("Unknown Block");
}
```

gets executed anyway because it's after the if else blocks. Semicolon effectively terminates the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals` instead of `==` to comapre strings.
See: http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/